# How do you find and fix degenerate and overlapping edges?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, edges

[image]

As you can see in the picture attached, 3d print tool box isn't finding problems with the mesh, however there are degenerate and overlapping edges. How do I identify and fix these issues without using degenerate dissolve?

[image]

Comment: The problem is your object is at an incredibly large scale which causes floating point precision problems. try playing with the camera clip min and max distance to stabilise display

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on *gorgious*`s point I just realised your mesh is incredibly huge after reading his comment and instead of 'playing with the camera clip min and max distance' like *gorgious* said just try selecting your mesh and press **'S'** to scale and type in a small value like **'0.006'** to decrease the size of your object.

Now press the period key on your keyboard to zoom into your object.
The period key is located under the **'3 Pgdn' key and left to the enter button.**

[image]

**A GIF for a better understanding**

[image]

Comment: Both Gorgious and Ribbit12 had great solutions to my camera/object scale problem. Turns out it wasn't overlapping or degenerate edges - it was a viewport issue.